# modalBottomSheet is overlapped up by the keyboard

Tags: flutter

It's written [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/67b5bdf99b19e5f04bae5fb82af91aa695fbfbb9/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart#L907) That

```
/// The scaffold will expand to fill the available space. That usually
/// means that it will occupy its entire window or device screen. When
/// the device's keyboard appears the Scaffold's ancestor [MediaQuery]
/// widget's [MediaQueryData.viewInsets] changes and the Scaffold will
/// be rebuilt. By default the scaffold's [body] is resized to make
/// room for the keyboard.
```

According to this if there is a TextField at the bottom, the `Scaffold` will resize itself and it does happen. But when I put a `TextField` inside a `modalBottomSheet` it doesn't get pushed up by the keyboard. The Keyboard overlaps the `modalBottomSheet` (with the `TextField`). If the `Scaffold` itself gets resized how `modalBottomSheet` stays at its place? And `resizeToAvoidBottomInset`has no effect on `modalBottomSheet`.
Here is the sample code.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context, builder: (context) => ShowSheet());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShowSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      child: TextField(
        autofocus: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I apologize if this question is dumb but I didn't understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know the reason may be because `modalBottomSheet` is using `PopupRoute` so it's a different route not sure. Anyway, here I found the solution I just needed to put some bottom viewInsets padding.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: 200,
        child: TextField(
          autofocus: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Also I needed to set `isScrollControlled: true,` of `showModalBottomSheet()`